# Mootools inject not working on ul correct

Tags: mootools, inject

In page I have that code:

```
<ul>
<li>Name 1</li>
<li>Name 2</li>
<li>Name 3</li>
<li>Name 4</li>
<li id="beforeInsert"></li>
</ul>
```

And I try to inject some of these code:

```
<li>Name 5</li>
<li>Name 6</li>
<li>Name 7</li>
```

before `<li id="beforeInsert"></li>` element whith that function:

```
html.inject("beforeInsert", "before");
```

But this function just add a first `<li>` element from my second list, in `<ul>` block. What I do wrong?

Comment: can you show a bit more script ? How is html defined ?

Comment: Show us your code. We can't fix your code if we can't see it!

Comment: here is a Fiddle that may help : http://jsfiddle.net/hQnvf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inject function works on mootools dom elements. so you can do something like this:

```
var el_before = document.id('beforeInsert');
[5,6,7].each(function(num){
   var li = new Element('li').set('html','Name ' + num);
   li.inject(el_before,'before');
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QrEJY/)